# Customise Community URL

Tags: community, custom-url

I would like to customize the Community URL so that all pages point to XYZcommunity.org/....

Currently when users type in www.XYZcommunity.org it redirects to https://XYZ.force.com/s/login/?language=en_GB&startURL=/s/&ec=302

Could we have the default url as www.XYZcommunity.org without it redirecting to a force.com url?

It would also be good if the url for all pages started with this url. E.g. If I click on the knowledge page, instead of: https://XYZ.force.com/s/knowledge/Knowledge__c/Recent 
the url should say: https://XYZcommunity.org/knowledge

When clicking on a Knowledge record, instead of the following url: https://XYZ.force.com/s/knowledge/a5Z1L000000AK5YUAW/a-quarterly-feedback-form-for-mentors 
The url should say: https://XYZcommunity.org/knowledge/a-quarterly-feedback-form-for-mentors

Answer (score 1):

As for your question:

> Could we have the default url as www.XYZcommunity.org without it redirecting to a force.com url?

The answer is **Yes**. You can run your community under a custom domain. You can get more details on the overall process on the knowledge article -- [Run your community under a custom domain](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212707&type=1).

> The force.com domain works for community use cases where the nature of the community is private, and where you're not looking for people to discover your community by its domain name. But many Salesforce customers want to run their community under their own domain (e.g. community.mycompany.com)...for both branding and SEO purposes. Since the Summer '14 release, all Community Cloud customers have had the ability to create a custom domain, upload their SSL certificate, and run their community under that domain.

The process involves your company's IT infrastructure team to make updates on your company's DNS servers as well as updates are needed on Salesforce end too. The updates are on your company's DNS servers by adding a CNAME record to point to your community. Then you upload the SSL certificate provided by the IT team in Salesforce.

While you will get complete details on the knowledge article, keep a note of few things as below (this is based on my experience around similar implementation):

1. CNAME takes around 24 hours to propagate, so you may not actually see the difference until that time
2. Make sure the Organization Id used in CNAME record is that of 18 characters. We had an issue around this.
3. Certificate uploads in Salesforce can take few hours to be propagated within Salesforce infrastructure